Which atom is larger? Neon or sodium?
Are noble gase atoms larger than alkali metals'? Does this obey periodicty? Or can they even be compared?

It is unclear what resources you have consulted before asking this question and what conclusion you have made from that. These data is easy to find.

I think you're comparing vdW radius with atomic, or ionic radius...

You can compare corresponding Noble Gases and Alkali metals through data and through some periodicity trends
If you want which single atom is larger, sodium has a larger radii than neon. If you are looking for an explanation, sodium has an extra shell than neon so the distance from outer electron to the nucleus is much higher. So you can use trends and data sheets to compare their radii. Then atomic radii decreases across a period so while Group 1 are least contracted, Noble Gases are most contracted
In general, Even the largest noble gas radii (Xenon) has a calculated atomic radii of 120 pm while sodium is 190 pm so alkali metals have larger radii.
